# Angular 2 + local storage + JWT for IE9+?

Tags: angular, local-storage, jwt

Can someone tell me how can I use local storage in Angular2 for IE9+? 
I've tried this tutorial https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-authentication-revisited-611bf7373bf9#.h42z63t9v, but my Angular 2 is not recognising the

```
import localStorage from 'localStorage';
```

It is giving me this error

```
Cannot find module 'localStorage'.
```

I know that IE9 is not supported by Angular2, however, there is a good work around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to import `localStorage` it is globally available. Article seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Oh! I just realised that. There is import localStorage from 'localStorage'; in the article and that made me confused!

That worked! Tks

Comment: Spot on man. I went through many question which uses third party plugin for localstorage, but i think there is no need as angular 2 already took care of it.